# Passing parameters to nginx url

Tags: node.js, nginx, redirect

How to pass parameters in nginx url. When I hit `http://127.0.0.1:1000/samp/test1/result?num1=10&num2=30`, it should redirect me to `http://127.0.0.1:80/samp/test1/result?num1=10&num2=30`. Is this possible? Below is my nginx config file.

```
upstream apache {
server 127.0.0.1:1000;
}
server {
listen       80;
server_name  127.0.0.1;
location / {
    #root   html;
    #index  index.html index.htm;
    #return 503;
    proxy_pass          http://apache;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused what you're asking.  You have an upstream `apache` configured to be reached on port 1000 and you have nginx listening on port 80.  If you go directly to port 1000 you are bypassing nginx entirely - meaning, nginx can't rewrite that request.

Comment: @Dan Farrell If I hit port 1000, then it should redirect me to nginx port since I want all requests to be served by 80.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is possibe, but you'd have to make that configuration change on the apache end of things.

If 'apache' handles a request coming into port 1000 directly, it will see a URI like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:1000/samp/test1/result?num1=10&num2=30
```

However, if it is sent through nginx, it will look more like this:

```
http://apache/samp/test1/result?num1=10&num2=30
```

So, you could check the incoming URL for :1000 and then rewrite the request on the apache side to go to port 80 instead ( which is the default, so you don't need `:80` - you can just leave the port unspecified entirely.

If the backend really is apache, you can use a rewrite rule there to handle the rewriting.

However, if you're not already on port 80, you're not connecting to nginx - so nginx can't rewrite this for you.

Hope it makes sense!

Here's how I tested:

Apache side I used a quick sinatra (ruby) app to print out the full URI of the request it sees:

```
require 'sinatra'

set :bind, "0.0.0.0"
set :port, 1025

get "/*" do
"<p>Hello from \"apache\"!  You've just requested:
<code>#{request.url}</code></p>
"
end
```

Then nginx is configured thusly:

```
upstream apache {
    server 192.168.70.1:1025;
}

server {
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://apache;
    }

}
```

Note I used port 1025, because port 1000 is a privileged port.

I used curl to generate the requests to test:

```
$ curl 'http://192.168.70.1:1025/samp/test1/result?num1=10&num2=30'
<p>Hello from "apache"!  You've just requested:
<code>http://192.168.70.1:1025/samp/test1/result?num1=10&num2=30</code></p>
$curl 'http://127.0.0.1:80/samp/test1/result?num1=10&num2=30'
<p>Hello from "apache"!  You've just requested:
<code>http://apache/samp/test1/result?num1=10&num2=30</code></p>
```

If I wanted to do the redirect you're describing, I could match with a regular expression of IPV4 address and port and redirect as such:

```
get "/*" do

    if request.url =~ %r|^http://([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}:1025/|
        redirect "http://localhost:80/#{request.fullpath}"
    else
"<p>Hello from \"apache\"!  Tou've just requested:
<code>#{request.url}</code></p>
"
    end
end
```

Now I tell `curl` to follow redirects (-L) and we see it redirect me over to the "correct" route.

```
$ curl -L 'http://192.168.70.1:1025/samp/test1/result?num1=10&num2=30'
<p>Hello from "apache"!  Tou've just requested:
<code>http://apache/samp/test1/result?num1=10&num2=30</code></p>
```

I know it's not the language you're using, but I hope it iwll help you get started.

Comment: Note that in the real world, this is rarely necessary, because usually your external frontend ( nginx in your case ) would be the only part of the stack listening on an externally accessible IP.  Apache would be on localhost ( or perhaps an internal IP on a different system, as in my example ) and therefore there would be no way to reach it via the "incorrect" URL anyway.  There are ways to enforce this even on localhost at the OS layer (eg iptables) - but like I said, to do that would be unusual since the backends aren't generally publicly accessible anyway.